# Combine different model output in keras

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network

Hi I have a task where in I have to combine many models that I have already trained. Now I want to merge all the models and get a single output without any further training. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tak a look at Keras [Merge Layers](https://keras.io/layers/merge/).

Consider the following toy example. Here we create two models, load their weights and combine them into a single merged model.

```py
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input, AvgPool2D, concatenate


def get_model1(input_shape):
    input_layer = Input(input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
    x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    model = Model(input_layer, x)
    return model

def get_model2(input_shape):
    input_layer = Input(input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_layer)
    x = Conv2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = AvgPool2D((5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    model = Model(input_layer, x)
    return model

model1 = get_model1(input_shape)
model1.load_weights('your_path_to_model1_weights')

model2 = get_model2(input_shape)
model2.load_weights('your_path_to_model2_weights')

# Combine two models
# concat_axis is the axis along which tensors are concatenated. 
# If you are working with images, then it is usually the channel axis.
merged_model = concatenate([model1, model2], axis=concat_axis)
```

Comment: How about the input? I am trying a similar thing, but it expects three inputs instead of 1 for fitting the model